# Appending Javascript in Rails using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Javascript where I render a partial using the `js.erb`:

```
$('#registration-steps').fadeOut("fast").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial =>   @page, :layout => false )%>").fadeIn("slow");
```

The problem is, in this partial I have some code from adwords I want to render for conversion tracking:

E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
```

When I call the partial however, the script is being stripped and the javascript is not being executed.

I tried the following in my `js.erb` with no avail:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js";
$("#tracking").append(script);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to dynamically execute the script using jQuery's getScript function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/`

However, that still means that the script include in your partial is mangled when you escape_javascript.

As another possibility you could move the  include out of your partial and add a content_for call to your layout:

```
<% =content_for :ad_words %>
```

Then at the end of your `js.erb` file I would insert it:

```
<% content_for :ad_words do %>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
<% end %>
```

That way there's no longer a chance it will be escaped.